# Perform transactional database operations asynchronously in .NET 4.5.1

Tags: c#, sql, async-await, transactional-database

I have written a program to perform database operations in asynchronous fashion.  I try to run it in a database transaction using BeginTransaction() or TransactionScope but have no luck.  I stepped through the code in VS2012 and noticed the execution would jump out the foreach loop when it sees the await for ExecuteNonQueryAsync.

```
public delegate void CallBackMethod();

public async Task MyFunction(List<string> items, CallBackMethod functionToCallBeforeCommitTransaction)
{   
    using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope(
                                               TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                                               TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled ))
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MySproc", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", item);
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();  
                // ^^^ Execution jumps out here and returns back to the calling function. 
                //     No exception was raised.  It did not continue the loop.
            }
        }
        functionToCallBeforeCommitTransaction();
        trans.Complete();
    }
}
```

Edited: Includes method header/signature.

Comment: Could you show the method signature...

Comment: How did you call `MyFunction`? Did you `await` it?

Comment: What behavior do you see? Exception? Deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John! You got it right!!

I forgot to use await or .Wait() in the caller.  I was so focus into the asynchronous support issue for transaction prior to .NET 4.5.1

```
await MyFunction();
```

or

```
MyFunction().Wait();
```

By the way, [.NET 4.5.1 Developer Pack (KB2878632)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2878632) needs to be installed so you can change the project target from .NET Framework 4.0 to 4.5.1

Comment: Depending on your environment (your blocking function is running on the single thread the `SyncroizationContext` will marshal it's calls to) doing `MyFunction().Wait()` will cause your code to deadlock.